# Template Metaprogramming and Turing Completeness

Tags: pl.programming-languages, computability, turing-machines

I am trying to design a Turing Machine using C++ Template Metaprogramming. What steps must be taken to ensure that the code that I'm gonna write will *actually* build a Turing machine ? I have read that C++ templates are Turing complete but I don't actually know how to prove this thing.

How should I proceed? Turing completeness is really tough to understand and so simulating a Turing Machine would be tougher I guess. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: (1) May I ask you why you want to implement a Turing machine using C++ templates?  (2) I do not know much about C++ and I do not know the proof of Turing completeness of C++ template metaprogramming either, but I would guess that you have to understand the proof first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The article you want is [C++ Templates are Turing Complete](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.120.2003&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Todd Verhuizen. It explains how things work in sufficient details. If you can faithfully encode a Turing machine and its behaviour in C++ templates, then this is sufficient to demonstrate Turing completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Since templates are a compile-time applicative language you may find it tedious to encode a stateful model of computation like a Universal Turing Machine. Encoding some other Turing-equivalent model, like the Lambda Calculus, is a more straight forward approach.

Answer (score 1):

The following post on StackOverflow might be useful: [What is Turing Complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7284/459391)

You may also consult the corresponding [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

Moreover, you may consider taking a look at [C++ Simulator of a Turing Machine](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/turing-mach/) before implementing one from scratch (unless your objective is to learn, rather than use).

Comment: Sadeq, he wants to do the implementation using C++ templates, not just regular C++. It's a whole new level of insanity.